# Jenkins, Perforce and Multibranch, how to set up automatic branch detecting?

Tags: jenkins, perforce, jenkins-multibranch

I'm setting up Jenkins with Pipeline (former Workflow) and trying to configure Multibranch. All documentation I find is about git and svn, but I'm stuck with using Perforce. I have installed all plugins, including p4 (the new Perforce plugin). Setting up a Multibranch job, I'm provided with a dropdown list under `Branch Sources` called `Add source`, with only the item called `Single repository & branch`. If selecting this, here is the description:

> Allows a single, fixed branch of some repository to be configured. **Not
>   normally used**, as it does not allow branches to be detected
>   automatically. Might be used, for example, if you want to build all
>   branches of one repository, and the master branch of a special clone.

For me, automatic detection of branches is essential. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the reason. It is not yet supported. There is a Jenkins JIRA issue with Major priority level.

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-32616

You need to create a user account and be logged in to read the link above.